# Android: displaying message and contacts on toast

Tags: android, toast

I want to make a toast where it shows "Your message "message" is sent to "contact" and I don't know how to do this, here's my code.

```
if (phoneNo.length()>0 && message.length()>0)   
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                                "Your message " + "&quot;" + message + "&quot;" + "is sent to " + phoneNo, 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: So what is the problem?? It gives you any error???

Comment: I want to achieve this output: "Your message "message" is sent to "contact" All I'm getting is  "Your message &quot;"message"&quot is sent to "contact"

Comment: then use @YashwanthKumar answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use This Simple,

```
 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),  
                  "Your message " + "\"" + message + "\"" + " is sent to " +"\""+ phoneNo+"\"",  
                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: @YashwanthKumar when you can't understand the question..other have posted the correct one and this answer is posted before you updated..so first understand ques then write ans

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"Your message \"" + message + " \" is sent to \"" + contact + " \""
```

Comment: error I want to achieve this: "Your message "message" is sent to "contact"

Comment: what he means is for you to use \" instead of &quot;

Comment: check my answer, again, i just changed how to use quotes you use them with \" like this inside a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Your message " + "&quot;" + message + "&quot;" + "is sent to " + PhoneNo, 
 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Toast.makeText(className.this, "Your message " + message + " is sent to " + phoneNo,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```